# three.js fbxloader example 99% success

Tags: three.js

This example page https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_fbx shows a model bot dancing samba. 
How can I get my hands on the model used by this page ?
I downloaded my own from mixamo.com and it gets loaded w/o problems, seems
to have all the animations and mixers, but I do not see the dancing bot character (the screen changes color to the colors of the bot once the scenes.add(object) is executed).
Am doing this with Angular6 and it really works very well with it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [example models are here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/models/fbx), if that's what you're asking?

Comment: Yes that is what I was asking for.
I will try using this one and see if it works.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Don,
Just reporting back that it works. The issue was not the model, I have tried now with several others from Mixamo.com and they work fine. The issue was with me using a different FBXLoader than THREE.FBXLoader as it was saying "not a constructor". 
I resolved that issue ( It needed inflate.min.js ) everything works now.
Am the CTO of a small firm by day and musician by night, my goal is to get some of my music and these animations linked up somehow. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked OK!

Answer (score 2):

The three.js FBX example models are hosted here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/models/fbx